# In relational algebra, does the DISTINCT have a symbol?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

To write this in relational algebra how do I specify the `DISTINCT` keyword?

```
SELECT DISTINCT FacultyName from Faculty;
```

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. PS But normally a relation is a set--no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

In a relational model, relationships are **sets** of tuples that, by definition, do not contain "duplicate" records.

Comment: They aren't "eliminated", they aren't produced. They might be produced or eliminated by some non-relation operators that you decide to use in some description of what the realtion operators return.

Comment: You're right. More precisely, I mean that in a relational model, relationships are sets of tuples that, by definition, do not contain “duplicate” records.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.